# How to make this vertical space closer?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

The problem, How to make this space closer?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!
    var imageArray = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mainScrollView.frame = view.frame
        imageArray = ["tumblr1","tumblr3","tumblr2","tumblr4","tumblr5"]

        for i in 0..<imageArray.count
        {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.image = imageArray[i]
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

            let yPosition = self.view.frame.height * CGFloat(i)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yPosition, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
            mainScrollView.contentSize.height = mainScrollView.frame.height * CGFloat(i + 1)
            mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want variable height or, fixed height for each image?

Comment: Why don't you simply use a UITableView instead of calculating and doing stuffs?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is:

```
let yPosition = self.view.frame.height * CGFloat(i)
```

Try making yPosition:

```
let yPosition = previousImage.frame.origin.y+previousImage.frame.size.height
```

Just keep track of the previous image before moving to the next image. Also set the height of the `imageView` to the height of the image, not the view.

You may want to change your for loop to this:

```
 var yPosition = 0

for i in 0..<imageArray.count
{
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = imageArray[i]
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yPosition, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

    yPosition += imageView.image?.size.height
    mainScrollView.contentSize.height = yPosition
}
```